# Solving for x using two derivatives and algebra.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

There are two things I don't understand about the following:

"

Set these derivatives equal to each other and solve the resulting equation.

$2\sqrt3\cos(x) = 2\sin(x)$

$= \sqrt3 = \tan(x)$ (since $\cos(x)$ can't be 0)

On the specified domain $[0, 2\pi]$ that means that:

$x = \frac13\pi$ and $x = \frac43\pi$

"

1. Why can't $\cos(x)$ be zero - surely it is 0 at $\frac12\pi$ and $\frac34\pi$, which are both in the domain.
2. Why $x = \frac{\pi}3$ and $x = \frac{4\pi}3$ - this is a non-calculator problem$\ldots$

Comment: $\cos$ can't be zero because $\sin$ is not zero when $\cos$ is, so that isn't a solution to the equation.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $\sqrt{3}$ is a special value of $\tan$ which you are expected to have memorized.

Answer (score 2):

If $2\sqrt{3}\cos{x}=2\sin{x}$, then $\cos{x}$ cannot be $0$ because $\sin{x}$ and $\cos{x}$ are never both $0$ for a single $x$. I'm not quite sure I understand your second question, but if this is a non-calculator problem then you leave the answer as a multiple of $\pi$ and don't approximate it with a demical number.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question:

You probably have to know that $\tan \frac{\pi}{3} = \sqrt{3}$, as well as $\tan \frac{\pi}{4} = 1$ and $\tan \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3}$. At least I know one had to learn these values for an exam.

They also follow from the unit circle and the relation $\tan(x)= \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$.

You should also know that $\tan$ is periodic with $\pi$, so that $\tan \frac{4\pi}{3} = \tan \frac{\pi}{3} = \sqrt{3}$.

I think that if you remember these four simple facts (three values and periodicity), you will be all right.